# Implementing Dynamic IP Fallback Mechanism with Connman

Tags: shell-script, debian, ip, dhcp, connman

I am working on a Debian 11-based live USB distribution that utilizes Connman for network management. However, as this distribution may run on various computers with different network interface card identifiers, I am looking for a way to assign a distinct static IP to each machine. To achieve this, I plan to store the static IP in a file on each USB.

To ensure network connectivity with the defined ips in a multi-instance environment, I would like to implement a mechanism that attempts to use the static IP upon booting the system. However, if there is no successful ping to an external server (e.g., google.com) or any other way to know the ip has been correctly leased, I want the system to fallback to DHCP for obtaining an IP dynamically.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to implement this dynamic IP fallback mechanism effectively. Thank you.